# Why attributes of bundle items of a bundle product are also saved to the bundle product itself? (database-wise)

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, database, eav, bundle-product

Recently I was studying how the options of the layered navigation filter on the category page are determined and retrieved. I have dug a bit into the models and database for it, and there I found the following mechanism which I do not understand:

**Situation:**
Say, I have an attribute named `color` (attribute_id = 133), a simple product `A` (entity_id = 26), and a bundled product `B` (entity_id = 27), and `A` is added to `B` as its bundle item, in `Magento ver. 1.9.0.1`.

**Step 1:** `color` is not set for both `A` and `B`

[image]

**Step 2:** `color` is set as `Black` (value_id = 19) for `B`

[image]

**Step 3:** `color` is set as `White` (value_id = 18) for `A`

[image]

From step 3, we could see that apparently attributes of the bundle items (`A` in this case) are also saved as if they are the attributes of the bundle product (`B` in this case) itself. And I believe that this is why the attributes of the bundle items of bundle products also appear in the layered navigation filter.

I would like to ask why is it designed this way? Why would the system save attributes of the children products to the parent product as well? How does it help in any specific process in the system?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same way with configurable products.

If you are looking for white shoes and the configurable products solves this problem for you, the product is offered. I think it is easy as this. So if your searched product is part of a bundle product, this product is offered too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your points, but I am curious why it has to be achieved this way? 'Cause it seems to me that it kind of lowers the flexibility when someone would not want the attributes of the children products to be hooked up with the parent product (or they simply do not want attributes of children products to show up in the filter). And I am not sure what purposes this "mechanism" serve, other than preparing data for the filter. So I am not sure if I could remove this step safely without tampering other parts of the system.

Comment: You don't. Remove it and then test. I think it is no problem. In the past I only added information, never removed some. But still: try and test :-) Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. In the end I figured out those "links" are actually created during product attributes re-indexing. So I guess those relations are created for faster searching and filtering purposes, and it should be fine to remove them. Thanks again.

Comment: @d.yuk I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Could you post how you achieved this with the indexer?

Comment: @AaronPollock I have edited the question and put the method there. Hope it could help. Good luck!

Comment: @d.yuk thanks for adding it, but it would be great if you 1. add it as an answer, so we can upvote it, 2. include it as text. Nothing is more annyoing then typing code if you could copy it :D

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Oh, I thought that I could no longer add that as an answer, as there was already an accepted one. And sorry for any inconvenience caused by the screen capture. My bad. :P

Comment: @d.yuk thanks for that! I'll take a look when I'm back from holiday.

Answer (score 7):

**Update: how to stop the indexer from including child products**

1. Extend and modify
   `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract`.
2. Look for the function `_prepareRelationIndex()`.
3. Modify the SQL query builder statement as follows:

Code:

```
$select = $write->select()
    ->from(array('l' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_relation')), 'parent_id')
    ->join(
        array('cs' => $this->getTable('core/store')),
        '',
        array())
    ->join(
        array('i' => $idxTable),
        'l.child_id = i.entity_id AND cs.store_id = i.store_id',
        array('attribute_id', 'store_id', 'value'))
    ->join(
        array('e' => 'catalog_product_entity'),
        'l.parent_id = e.entity_id',
        array())
    ->group(array(
        'l.parent_id', 'i.attribute_id', 'i.store_id', 'i.value'
    ))
    ->where('e.type_id != ?', 'bundle');
```

[image: how to stop the indexer from including child products]
<sub>**reference**: addition of codes highlighted in red</sub>

Comment: How to do it on magento 2